# Verification of algorithm for variant of gas station

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

[image]

I am studying this problem and I recognise this as a variant of the gas station problem. As a result, I use Greedy algorithm to solve this problem. I would like to ask if anyone helps me to point out my algorithm is correct or not, thanks.

My algorithm

```
  var x = input.distance, cost = input.cost, c = input.travelDistance, price = [Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY];
  var result = [];

  var lastFill = 0, tempMinIndex = 0, totalCost = 0;

  for(var i=1; i<x.length; i++) {
    var d = x[i] - x[lastFill];
    if(d > c){ //car can not travel to this shop, has to decide which shop to refill in the previous possible shops
      result.push(tempMinIndex);
      lastFill = tempMinIndex;
      totalCost += price[tempMinIndex];
      tempMinIndex = i;
    }
    //calculate price
    price[i] = d/c * cost[i];
    if(price[i] <= price[tempMinIndex])
      tempMinIndex = i;
  }

  //add last station to the list and the total cost
  if(lastFill != x.length - 1){
    result.push(x.length - 1);
    totalCost += price[price.length-1];
  }
```

You can try out the algorithm at this link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4sd8MQwTpVnMXdCRU0xZFlVRlk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, regarding to your solution.

There is a bug that ruins even at the most simple inputs. When you decided that the distance became too far and you should fulfil at some point before, you don't update distance and gas station charge you more that it should. The fix is simple:

```
if(d > c){ 
//car can not travel to this shop, has to decide which shop to refill
//in the previous possible shops
      result.push(tempMinIndex);
      lastFill = tempMinIndex;
      totalCost += price[tempMinIndex];
      tempMinIndex = i;
      // Fix: update distance
      var d = x[i] - x[lastFill];
    }
```

Even with this fix, your algorithm fails on some input data, like this:

```
0 10 20 30
0 20 30 50
30
```

It should refill on every gasoline to minimize cost, but it simply fills on the last one.

After some research, I came up with solution. I'll try to explain it as simple as possible to make it language independent.

1. Idea

For every gas station `G` we will count cheapest way of filling. We'll do that recursively: for each gas station let's find all gas stations `i` from which we can reach `G`. For every `i` count cheapest filling possible and sum up with the cost of the filling at `G` given gasoline left. For start gas station cost is 0. More formally:
[image: MinGasStation function definition]

[image: Cost function definition]

[image: BestCost function definition]

`CostOfFilling(x)`, `Capacity` and `Position(x)` can be retrieved from input data.

So, the answer for the problem is simply `BestCost(LastGasStation)`

2. Code

Now, solution in javascript to make things clearer.

```
function calculate(input)
{
    // Array for keeping calculated values of cheapest filling at each station
    best = [];
    var x = input.distance;
    var cost = input.cost;
    var capacity = input.travelDistance;

    // Array initialization
    best.push(0);
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++)
    {
        best.push(-1);
    }

    var answer = findBest(x, cost, capacity, x.length - 1);
    return answer;
}

// Implementation of BestCost function
var findBest = function(distances, costs, capacity, distanceIndex)
{
    // Return value if it's already have been calculated
    if (best[distanceIndex] != -1)
    {
        return best[distanceIndex];
    }
    // Find cheapest way to fill by iterating on every available gas station
    var minDistanceIndex = findMinDistance(capacity, distances, distanceIndex);
    var answer = findBest(distances, costs, capacity, minDistanceIndex) + 
        calculateCost(distances, costs, capacity, minDistanceIndex, distanceIndex);
    for (var i = minDistanceIndex + 1; i < distanceIndex; i++)
    {
        var newAnswer = findBest(distances, costs, capacity, i) + 
        calculateCost(distances, costs, capacity, i, distanceIndex);
        if (newAnswer < answer)
        {
            answer = newAnswer;
        }
    }
    // Save best result
    best[distanceIndex] = answer;
    return answer;
}

// Implementation of MinGasStation function
function findMinDistance(capacity, distances, distanceIndex)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < distances.length; i++)
    {
        if (distances[distanceIndex] - distances[i] <= capacity)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

// Implementation of Cost function
function calculateCost(distances, costs, capacity, a, b)
{
    var distance = distances[b] - distances[a];
    return costs[b] * (distance / capacity);
}
```

Full workable html page with code is available [here](http://pastebin.com/NJqFTiQW)

Comment: Sorry, but I find that there is a counter-test case for your solution, if I use [0 13 25 26 47 49 52 63 100], [0 56 42 46 56 13 98 42 13] and 40. Your solution gives out 56.62499999 while the minimum cost is 53.525, would you like to check what's wrong with that?

Comment: @user2534365 can you please provide solution (correct gas stations) to this example if you have it?

Comment: One more thing, I would like to ask what code do I have to add if I want to know which stops to stop?

Comment: @user2534365 that is tricky one; I thought for myself but didn't got any ideas. I will try again in a few days when I have enough time to concentrate, but I don't give any promises. If you will be lucky to find answer to this question, tell me please.

Comment: Found a solution to calculate the stops to stop, [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4sd8MQwTpVnYkY2X0hVemZ1U0k/view?usp=sharing). Moreover, can I say your solution is O(n^2)?

Comment: @user2534365 yes, it's O(n^2) where n is obviously the number of gas stations.